# Pre-fill fields automatically

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a "Produits" table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('reference')->nullable();
            $table->string('libelle')->nullable();
            $table->string('entrepot_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('tva')->nullable();
            $table->string('etat_vente')->nullable();
            $table->string('etat_achat')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('limit_stock_alerte')->nullable();
            $table->string('stock_optimal')->nullable();
            $table->string('prix_vente')->nullable();
            $table->string('prix_vente_min')->nullable();
            $table->string('prix_revient')->nullable();
            $table->string('poids')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_created_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_updated_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My controller which allows me to retrieve the list of "Produits"

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $propositions = PropoCom::where('id','=',$id)->first();
        $produits = Produit::where('etat_vente', 1)->get();
        return view('layouts.commerce.details-propo-brouillon', compact('propositions', 'produits'));
    }
```

My form:

```
<form action="">
    <tr>
   @foreach ($produits as $produit)
   <th scope="row">
   <label for="inputEmail4">Produits prédéfinis en vente</label>
   <select id="inputState" class="form-control w-75 mb-3">
   <option>...</option>
   <option>{{$produit->reference}} - {{$produit->libelle}} - 
   @if ($produit->stocks->isNotEmpty())
   {{ $produit->stocks->sortByDesc('created_at')->first()->nbr_piece }}
   @else
   @endif - {{ number_format($produit->prix_vente, 0, ',', ' ') }} FCFA
   </option>
   @endforeach
   </select>
   </th>
   <td>
   <label for="inputEmail4">TVA</label>
   <select id="inputState" class="form-control w-100 mt-2">
   <option>...</option>
   <option>0%</option>
   <option selected>18%</option>
   </select>
   </td>
   <td>
   <label for="inputEmail4">PRIX DE VENTE</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 mt-2">
   </td>
   <td>
   <label for="inputEmail4">QUANTITE</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 mt-2">
   </td>
   <td>
  <label for="inputEmail4">REDUCTION</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 mt-2">
  </td>
  <td>
  <label for="inputEmail4">PRIX DE REVIENT</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control w-75 mt-2">
  </td>
  <td>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4">AJOUTER</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

I would like when the user selects a product in the drop-down menu "

```
@foreach ($produits as $produit)
   <th scope="row">
   <label for="inputEmail4">Produits prédéfinis en vente</label>
   <select id="inputState" class="form-control w-75 mb-3">
   <option>...</option>
   <option>{{$produit->reference}} - {{$produit->libelle}} - 
   @if ($produit->stocks->isNotEmpty())
   {{ $produit->stocks->sortByDesc('created_at')->first()->nbr_piece }}
   @else
   @endif - {{ number_format($produit->prix_vente, 0, ',', ' ') }} FCFA
   </option>
   @endforeach
```

" Other fields such as:

```
<label for="inputEmail4">TVA</label>
<select id="inputState" class="form-control w-100 mt-2">
<option>...</option>
<option>0%</option>
<option selected>18%</option>
</select>
```

and:

```
<label for="inputEmail4">PRIX DE VENTE</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control w-75 mt-2">
```

And:

```
<label for="inputEmail4">PRIX DE REVIENT</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control w-75 mt-2">
```

Automatically pre-populate with product information when the product is selected.
Any ideas how I can handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/). It helps creating dynamic interfaces with Laravel.

Or you could use JavaScript for that. Make a request to your server whenever your select change and populate your fields with the response.

Something like:

```html
<select id="inputState" class="form-control w-75 mb-3" onchange="populateProductInfo(this)">
    <!-- Options -->
</select>
```

```js
function populateProductInfo(selectedOption) {
    // Make a request to fetch product information based on the selected option value
    // Update other fields with the response
}
```